# Read RGB values

Tags: c, image, input, rgb, pixel

How can i read the rgb values of the first pixel?I do not want to use structs  or 2D arrays.Only 1D.Thanks in advance

```
#define SIZE 2048*2048*4
unsigned char image[2048*2048*4];    // Image as input

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  unsigned char *gray_image[2048*2048];
  unsigned char *ee_image[2048*2048]    
  char *filename = 0;   
  FILE *fp;  
  FILE *wp;
  int width=2048;
  int height=2048;
  int j, x, y, T;
  if (argc == 3){
    filename = argv[1];
    T = atoi(argv[2]);
  } else{
    printf("Give a bmp image and a threshold as input\n");
    exit(0);
  }
  // Opening the file: using "rb" mode to read this *binary* file
  printf("Opening filename: %s\n", filename);
  fp = fopen(filename, "rb");

  // initializationn part: read the input rgba file
}
```

Comment: What is the file format of the source file? Is it a .BMP file?

Comment: How many bytes/pixel? You have `image` which has 4 bytes/pixel but `gray_image` and `ee_image` have 1 byte/pixel.

Comment: _Side note:_ `gray_image` and `ee_image` are _stack_ based variables. They are 4MB in size each, for a total of 8MB. This will probably cause a stack overflow on most systems because the default stack size is approx 8MB. So, I'd make them global scope instead.

Comment: *gray_image* and *ee_image* are array of pointer to unsigned char, not array of unsigned char, you put in the stack 8 mega pointers to char, do you really want that ? You define *SIZE* but you do not use it at least for *image*. Look how much time you have 2048 in your code

Comment: @CraigEstey you miss the fact *gray_image* and *ee_image* are array of *pointer to unsigned char*, not array of unsigned char

Comment: If you're going to `#define` something *at least use it*. You should also avoid allocating large structures on the stack. Use `malloc` instead here. You define a lot of things here multiple times, like how `2048` appears over and over and over in the code.

Comment: @bruno Yup, just saw your prior comment. I was mainly commenting on the size, but OP probably wants [as you've mentioned] just `unsigned char` instead of `unsigned char *`

Comment: When you say "read" the first pixel, are you talking about how to load a given file format into memory (e.g. `.bmp`)? Or, because you want a 1D array, are you talking about how to access pixels as _if_ you had a 2D array (e.g. `my2d[y][x]` --> `my1d[(y * width) + x]`)?

Comment: @Craig Estey the second one and I want to read the rgb values